# VideoJS Audio But No Video

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I'm trying to host my videos with Vimeo and use VideoJS to display them on the front end. Here is the sample page:

https://jsfiddle.net/zhdnmxt8/

```
<div>
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
      controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto"
      data-setup='{}'>
            <source src="//player.vimeo.com[...]" type="video/mp4" data-quality="hd" data-res="HD" data-default="true">
            <source src="//player.vimeo.com/[...]" type="video/mp4" data-res="SD">
        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>.</p>
    </video>
</div>
```

Press Play to get the audio but there's no video that displays. Why is this?

**Note:** VideoJS CDN JS and CSS are included via *External Resources* at JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Set a height, auto won't do. Try for example `500px`, that should do it.

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zhdnmxt8/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Set a height and width.

```
width="500" height="500"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zhdnmxt8/1/

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I was going with an `auto` height and width is because I wanted to make the VideoJS container responsive. That's why I didn't want to hardcode the values into the player.

The best solution I found is at:

[video.js size to fit div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169473/video-js-size-to-fit-div)

with one minor change to the `.video-js` CSS override:

```
.video-js { padding-top: 56.25% }
```

(This ensures that the video displays in the viewport.) 56.25% is a magical 16:9 padding number that I found from this article (this full article didn't solve my problem completely but rather provided a missing puzzle piece):

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/videodrome/videojs/

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when i was playing video locally its given me same issue. It only play the audio with black screen but afterwards i uploaded same html file to the server and then i run it and now it playing both audio as well as video.