# Can't get Video.js plugin to work

Tags: javascript, video.js

I'm able to get Video.JS working but I'm not able to get the Resolution Switcher plugin working.

I just don't know where to put the code to get it work I think

I put this in my `<head>`

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.1/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using this code for where the video will be displayed

`<video id='video' class="video-js vjs-default-skin"></video>`

I put this right before my `<body>` ends

```
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.4/video.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/video.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/videojs-resolution-switcher.js"></script>
```

And this is placed afterwards

```
videojs('video', {
    controls: true,
    plugins: {
        videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
            default: 'high',
            dynamicLabel: true
        }
    }
}, function() {

    // Add dynamically sources via updateSrc method 
    player.updateSrc([{
        src: 'videos/intros/Intro480_30_Condensed.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        label: '480'
    }, {
        src: 'videos/intros/Intro720_30_Condensed.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        label: '720'
    }])

    player.on('resolutionchange', function() {
        console.info('Source changed to %s', player.src())
    })

})
```

And this is the error I get in the console

[image]

and nothing is playing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the code posted on [their github](https://github.com/videojs/video.js), the first line should be:

```
var player = videojs('video', {
```

And probably, into the callback function, instead of referring to `player`, you can just use `this`.

```
var player = videojs('video', {
    controls: true,
    plugins: {
        videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
            default: 'high',
            dynamicLabel: true
        }
    }
}, function() {

    // Add dynamically sources via updateSrc method 
    this.updateSrc([{
        src: 'videos/intros/Intro480_30_Condensed.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        label: '480'
    }, {
        src: 'videos/intros/Intro720_30_Condensed.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        label: '720'
    }])

    this.on('resolutionchange', function() {
        console.info('Source changed to %s', this.src())
    })

})
```

Comment: You are god's gift to mankind. Another quick question though, how can I set the max width and or height?

Comment: @CodingIsHardForMe You're welcome :) Consider upvoting and marking this as the answer for future visitors. :)

Comment: @CodingIsHardForMe That's another question, but I believe you can use CSS for those kind of things. Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169473/video-js-size-to-fit-div).